# How to print the content of popup only?

Tags: printing, popup, oracle-adf

I have a page doing some functionality and at the end it produces ***a report displayed  in a popup*** and I want to print this report **only** not the whole page.

How can I **print the the content of the popup**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup embeded into the page and there is no way to print only part of the page.
So you have to create separate page (which you can generate from the popup content) or use an iframe.